# How to configure browser used by web page Reminders?

Tags: macos, ios, siri, reminders

How can I change which browser the Mac Reminders.app uses to open "this webpage" associations for a Reminder, so I can change the "Open Google Chrome Canary" notification button to an "Open Mozilla Firefox" button?

Given I've created a Reminder for a Webpage on my phone by asking Siri to "remind me about this tomorrow", when the Reminder appears on my laptop running the latest public build of OS X, then I expect the Open button to offer to open it in my default browser, or just not mention the browser and behave as `open(1)` does.

Instead, what I see is "Open in Google Chrome Canary":

[image]

This has me flummoxed: I open that browser like once a year, and my default browser is Mozilla Firefox. I've no clue why Reminders has latched onto it as The Chosen Browser for webpage reminders.

**ETA:** I have deleted Google Chrome Canary. After relaunching Reminders.app, webpage reminders show, instead of its icon, the "invalid app" default icon with slashed-circle. Clicking that button does nothing. No console logs appear.

Comment: Can't believe there's no answer/fix for this yet. :(

Answer (score 1):

My results from user edgarator’s solution: **Successful for macOS Safari users**

### Summary

- Chrome icon changed to Safari after CleanMyMac Chrome Uninstall
- Chrome icon appears again after Chrome is reinstalled
- Removing files individually still had the Chrome icon, resulting in “no effect”
- Firefox will open Reminders URL’s if it is set as the default web browser.
- Firefox can’t share websites to Reminders.
- Firefox can’t use Siri to send websites to Reminders.

### Software Versions

- macOS Sierra:         10.12.6
- Apple Reminders:      4.0 (441.11)
- CleanMyMac:           1.10.4
- Google Chrome:        61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Safari:               10.1.2 (12603.3.8)
- Firefox:              55.0.3 (64-bit)

### My Process

Safari’s has a share website to Reminders feature (Share-to-Reminders).  Details can be added to a website reminder that is being sent to Reminders without leaving the browser.

Now the problem: The shared links in Reminders uses Chrome icons which open Reminders items in Chrome, instead of Safari—or a designated browser.
[image: Reminders links with Chrome's icon]
I used CleanMyMac to uninstall Google Chrome, it's folders, and files.

After uninstalling Chrome, it's icon was replaced by Safari’s icon, pressing on the icon opened the link in Safari.
[image: Safari's icon]
I then changed the default web browser to Firefox.

Clicking on the URL’s directly, or Control-clicking the URL’s in the Info Pane, opens the link in Firefox (default browser).

However, Firefox does not support Share-to-Reminders, so websites can’t be shared to Reminders from Firefox.  This also means that Siri does not execute the Share-to-Reminders command while using Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

[CleanMyMac 3](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) has a feature called "Rebuild Launch Services Database", which fixed the issue for me, resetting the browser from Chrome to Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (but wanted Safari to be the default) and found that un-registering and re-registering Safari with Launch Services got me the desired result:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/Safari.app`

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister /Applications/Safari.app`

Replace `/Applications/Safari.app` with your desired browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting these files:

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist`
- `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.google.Chrome.savedState`
- `/private/var/folders/5g/h3jsl4892418tz23ttcms4p80000gn/C/com.google.Chrome`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`
- `~/Library/Caches/com.google.Keystone.Agent`
- `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome`
- `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist`
- `~/Library/Google/Google Chrome Brand.plist`
- `~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate`

Not sure which one, but one of those fixes the problem. And removing them all will remove all of the files that Chrome installs in your system. I'm using [MacPaw's CleanMyMac 3](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) to do this automatically.

Comment: Some time later, it went from no browser to regular Chrome as the browser used to open reminders. I don't actually want to delete Chrome: I just don't want it to be the browser used to open webpage reminders!